# Binary Heap downheap method does not work properly

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-heap

I am trying to practice coding some data structures in Java, and have a problem with Binary Heap, I'd be very grateful if you could help me.

First I've made a class for objects that will be stored in the heap.

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;

public Person(String name, String surname, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
}

public void setName(String n) {
    name = n;
}

public void setSurname(String n) {
    surname = n;
}

public void setAge(int a) {
    age = a;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
}
```

Then I've made a class for heap nodes in which Person objects will be held as well as node priorities.

```
public class BinNode {

private Person element;
private int priority;

BinNode(Person element, int priority) {
    this.element = element;
    this.priority = priority;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (element == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public Person getElement() {
    return element;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data: " + element.getName() + " " + element.getSurname() + 
            ". Age: " + element.getAge() + "." + " Priority: " + priority + ".";
}   
}
```

And finally I've made a class for binary heap.

```
public class BinHeap {

public BinNode[] tab;
public int counter;

BinHeap(Person root, int priority) {
    counter = 1;
    tab = new BinNode[10];
    BinNode rt = new BinNode(root, priority);   
    tab[counter++] = rt;
}

public void upheap(int i) {
    while((i > 1) && (tab[i].getPriority() < tab[i-1].getPriority())) {
        BinNode temp = tab[i-1];
        tab[i-1] = tab[i];
        tab[i] = temp;
        i--;
    }
}

//error somewhere here
public void downheap(int i) {
    int l = 2 * i;
    int r = 2 * i + 1;      
    while (r < counter-1 && l < counter) {
        l = 2 * i;
        r = 2 * i + 1;
        if(tab[l].getPriority() < tab[r].getPriority()) {
            BinNode temp = tab[i];
            tab[i] = tab[l];
            tab[l] = temp;
            i = l;
        } else if (tab[l].getPriority() >= tab[r].getPriority()) {
            BinNode temp = tab[i];
            tab[i] = tab[r];
            tab[r] = temp;
            i = r;
        }   
    }   
}

public void insert(Person p, int priority) {
    BinNode node = new BinNode(p, priority);
    tab[counter++] = node;
    upheap(counter-1);
}

public BinNode findMin() {
    return tab[1];
}

//or here   
public void delMin() {
    tab[1] = tab[counter];
    tab[counter--] = null;
    downheap(1);
}

public void showTree() {
    for (int i = 1; i < tab.length; i++) {
        if(tab[i] != null) {
        System.out.println(i + " - " + tab[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

This Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person mary = new Person("Mary", "Green", 20);
    Person mark = new Person("Mark", "Yellow", 60);
    Person john = new Person("John", "Dark", 12);
    Person adam = new Person("Adam", "Bright", 30);
    Person martha = new Person("Martha", "King", 33);
    Person greg = new Person("Greg", "Pawn", 1);

    BinHeap heap = new BinHeap(mary, 2);
    heap.showTree();
    System.out.println();

    heap.insert(mark, 4);
    heap.insert(john, 12);

    heap.showTree();
    System.out.println();

    heap.insert(adam, 1);
    heap.showTree();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("root: " + heap.findMin().toString());
    System.out.println();

    heap.insert(martha, 5);
    heap.insert(greg, 15);

    heap.showTree();
    System.out.println();

    heap.delMin();
    heap.showTree();

}
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
1 - Data: Mary Green. Age: 20. Priority: 2.

1 - Data: Mary Green. Age: 20. Priority: 2.
2 - Data: Mark Yellow. Age: 60. Priority: 4.
3 - Data: John Dark. Age: 12. Priority: 12.

1 - Data: Adam Bright. Age: 30. Priority: 1.
2 - Data: Mary Green. Age: 20. Priority: 2.
3 - Data: Mark Yellow. Age: 60. Priority: 4.
4 - Data: John Dark. Age: 12. Priority: 12.

root: Data: Adam Bright. Age: 30. Priority: 1.

1 - Data: Adam Bright. Age: 30. Priority: 1.
2 - Data: Mary Green. Age: 20. Priority: 2.
3 - Data: Mark Yellow. Age: 60. Priority: 4.
4 - Data: Martha King. Age: 33. Priority: 5.
5 - Data: John Dark. Age: 12. Priority: 12.
6 - Data: Greg Pawn. Age: 1. Priority: 15.

1 - Data: Mary Green. Age: 20. Priority: 2.
2 - Data: Martha King. Age: 33. Priority: 5.
3 - Data: Mark Yellow. Age: 60. Priority: 4.
5 - Data: John Dark. Age: 12. Priority: 12.
6 - Data: Greg Pawn. Age: 1. Priority: 15.
```

As you can see, as long as we are putting new nodes into the heap it all works good. However when we want to delete the root node, downheap method (or perhaps delMin method) does not work properly.

**As you can see the node "Martha King" with priority of 5 is higher in the heap than "Mark Yellow" node with priority of 4.**

EDIT: It seems that I didn't understand how the binary heap behaves when implemented as an array. So the above sentence in bold is not true. The original output is wrong because the heap lost its completeness property, since array[4] is empty.

I just can't figure that one out. Could you please help me? Thank you. Also some general comments about coding style, etc. would be appreciated. This is my first post on stack overflow so sorry if I've messed something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In upheap you compare the values of new child with parent not with i-1.

```
int parent(int i)
{
    return i/2;
}

public void upheap(int i) {
    while((i > 1) && (tab[i].getPriority() < tab[parent(i)].getPriority())) {
        BinNode temp = tab[parent(i)]; // it should not be i-1 but parent of i that is i/2
        tab[parent(i)] = tab[i];
        tab[i] = temp;
        i = parent(i);
    }
}
```

Moreover in downheap

```
public void downheap(int i) {
    int l = 2 * i;
    int r = 2 * i + 1; 
    int small = i;     
    if(l<counter && tab[l].getPriority() < tab[small].getPriority())
         small = l;
    if(r<counter && tab[r].getPriority() < tab[small].getPriority())
         small = r;
    if(small!=i)
    {
        BinNode temp = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tab[small];
        tab[small] = temp;
        downheap(small); //you need to call downheap again on the small to find new pos for i (i became small after swap). 
        //i = 1, when you call downheap after delete. The node at i=1 will move down if it is bigger.
    }
}
```

Edit: As suggested by @ Łukasz Bieliński also correct your delMin() function

```
public void delMin() {
    tab[1] = tab[--counter];
    tab[counter] = null;
    downheap(1);
}
```

Below is the resulting image of the output and heap tree that will be produced on adopting above changes. And the results are correct.
[image: Result image]

You may refer to this article for code reference.

[Binary Heap](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-heap/)

The code is in c++ but will be clear for Java students as it is done using class.
MinHeapify is downheap function there and while loop inside insertKey() is upheap there. Also counter starts from 0 there not 1.

Comment: @greg_pio check it now, friend

Comment: Yes, it works correctly now. Thanks for the graph it helped me understand it. Łukasz - thanks for your feedback too!

Answer (score 0):

I think you hold next empty index in the counter variable. Implement @Adarsh Anurag corrections. And when deleting you mast get element before this empty index, not after.

```
public void delMin() {
    tab[1] = tab[--counter];
    tab[counter] = null;
    downheap(1); 
}
```